# awk script which sums the last 30days

Tags: awk

I have an awk code. But i have no idea how to modify it to sum only the last 30days.

My awk script:

```
awk -F";" '{sum+=$3} END{if (sum>1000) print "error=1"; else error="0"}' /tmp/$username
```

My input:

```
2014-05-19:10:54:36;coolpad;10;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;185;coolpad;END;
2014-07-19:12:10:42;coolpad;1;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;4415;csib;END;
2014-07-19:12:27:35;coolpad;50;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;748;coolpad;END;
2014-07-19:12:29:08;coolpad;2;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;88;coolpad;END;
2014-07-19:12:34:34;coolpad;7;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;291;coolpad;END;
2014-07-19:12:35:03;coolpad;4;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;26;coolpad;END;
2014-09-19:12:35:16;coolpad;0;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;12;coolpad;END;
2014-09-19:12:38:21;coolpad;0;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;60;coolpad;END;
2014-09-19:12:39:20;coolpad;0;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;58;coolpad;END;
2014-09-19:12:40:35;coolpad;0;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;74;coolpad;END;
2014-09-19:12:43:08;coolpad;0;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;118;coolpad;END;
2014-09-19:12:43:23;coolpad;0;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;14;coolpad;END;
2014-09-19:12:50:54;coolpad;0;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;349;coolpad;END;
2014-09-19:12:51:42;coolpad;0;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;47;coolpad;END;
2014-09-19:12:52:22;coolpad;0;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;39;coolpad;END;
2014-09-19:12:57:03;coolpad;0;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;281;coolpad;END;
```

So the amount is the 3rd.

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we have `date` to get 30 days ago:

```
$ date -d"-30 days" "+%Y-%m-%d:%T"
2014-08-20:15:55:42
```

Let's compare that value with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F";" -v d="$(date -d"-30 days" "+%Y-%m-%d:%T")" '$1>d {sum+=$3} END{print sum+0}' file
0
```

#### Explanation

- `-F";"` set input field separator as `;`.
- `-v d="$(date -d"-30 days" "+%Y-%m-%d:%T")"` provide the date of today - 30 days in the YYYY-MM-DD:HH:MM:SS format.
- `$1>d {sum+=$3}` if the date is bigger than the given one, add the 3rd column.
- `END{print sum+0}` print the result. In case `sum` was not set, it returns `0` with the `+0` trick.

---

See the matching itself:

```
$ awk -F";" -v d="$(date -d"-30 days" "+%Y-%m-%d:%T")" '$1>d' a
2014-09-19:12:35:16;coolpad;0;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;12;coolpad;END;
2014-09-19:12:38:21;coolpad;0;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;60;coolpad;END;
2014-09-19:12:39:20;coolpad;0;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;58;coolpad;END;
2014-09-19:12:40:35;coolpad;0;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;74;coolpad;END;
2014-09-19:12:43:08;coolpad;0;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;118;coolpad;END;
2014-09-19:12:43:23;coolpad;0;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;14;coolpad;END;
2014-09-19:12:50:54;coolpad;0;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;349;coolpad;END;
2014-09-19:12:51:42;coolpad;0;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;47;coolpad;END;
2014-09-19:12:52:22;coolpad;0;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;39;coolpad;END;
2014-09-19:12:57:03;coolpad;0;0;78.92.146.183;10.8.0.18;281;coolpad;END;
```

Comment: Dont know why, but it is not working. :/
This is the full script: http://pastebin.com/e0sX95mL

Know it is ugly, but worked. (except the plus code with the 30day calculate )

Comment: @csib why are you declaring the awk statement ?

Comment: Because later i need the error's value and without this i cant get it out of the if/while.

Comment: @csib `END{if (sum>1000) print "error=1"; else "error=1"}` does not make many sense. You are missing a `print` in the `else`.